# Best jQuery Youtube Popup for Websites Viewed on iPads

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-ui

What is the best jQuery youtube Popup for Websites Viewed on iPads?

A lot of plugins just don't work well on mobile, what jQuery movie popups work best.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at flowplayer. It has a ipad plugin built using jquery which works on ipad

http://flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/javascript/ipad.html

Answer (score 0):

I have [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) that load the movie in an iframe that popup and it's working pretty well. You might give it a try.